# how to avoid to fire form control valueChanges when undefined vs null

Tags: null, lodash, undefined, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Angular 8 And I have a form object and I have subscribed valuechanges in the following way:

```
        this.myFormSubscription = this.myForm.get(this.parentGroupName).valueChanges
            .pipe(
                startWith(null as string),
                pairwise(),
                debounceTime(100),
                distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => lodash.isEqual(a, b))
            )
            .subscribe(([prev, next]: [any, any]) => {
                //...do something
            });
```

The problem is that it fires when previous value is null and next value is undefined which for me the result of this comparison should be true and I don't need tracing these kind of changes.

And I also have to say I put the valuechanges on hole of the controllers in my form so the value of 'prev' and 'next' which subscribe method returns are always **objects** that are not just one level too!

for example like this:

```
prev = {a: 1, b: 2, c: {d: 3, e: null} };
next = {a: 1, b: 2, c: {d: 3, e: undefined} };
```

In this case the valuechanges event fires which I really need to stop that, Is there any way?

Or maybe I have to compare the previous and next value manually, right? Would be a good solution? Although that seems difficult and tricky to because the objects are two-level...
So what really I should do?!

Actually I am new at this, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to keep it simple and add as you go. In the most basic form does it work like this:

```
this.myFormSubscription = this.myForm.get(this.parentGroupName).valueChanges
            .subscribe((value) => {
                if (value) { <= If value is null or undefined, it will not continue.
                //...do something
               }
            });
```

UPDATE:

If your `FormGroup` looks like this (where c is the sub-group of myForm)

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
 a: [null],
 b: [null],
 c: this.fb.group({
   d: [null],
   e: [null],
 })
});
```

If you need to get the `valueChanges` of e. It would be like this

```
const cGroup = this.myForm.get('c') as FormGroup;
cGroup.get('e').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
 // Now you only have the value and changes of e in the formgroup of c
 if (value) {

 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes it seems a good and simple way. But as I updated my question , I bound the changevalue on hole controllers in the form (because I need calling just one method if each one of them changes) ...so In my case the value which subscribe method returns is always an object. So is there any way to compare to object ignoring null and undefined?...Thank you in advance

Comment: I provided additional explanation based on the object you provided in your updated question.

Comment: Ok I see...Thanks.